# Gradle offline mode - check online sources once a day

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I would like that gradle checks online sources for changes ONCE a day only, afterwards it should work offline for this day.

Is this possible? I don't want to have to enable offline mode in the settings and manually adjust this setting whenever I want gradle to check if everything is up to date...

Any ideas?

Alternatively, is it possible to enable offline mode via a gradle task or via a properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you may find it usefull not to set your build to offline mode, but rather to configure the cache to store dependencies longer. This could be done via [`resolutionStrategy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:controlling_caching) in your buildscript as follows:

```
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 10, 'days'
        resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10, 'days'
    }
}
```

In that case, Gradle will store dependencies in cache for 10 days and will not try to update it untill the time is passed. You can set it for a long time and sometimes call your build with `--refresh-dependencies` flag to refresh it manually.